# Is it possible to generate DB diagram for all SQL databases opened in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms, database-diagrams

At the present we have to go to each database and manually generate database diagrams, so I want a way to automate this.

Question: Is it possible to generate DB diagram for all SQL databases opened in SSMS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible

You have to go into each database and create database diagrams there